# OpenCV Video Recording Timing Errors

Tags: c++, opencv, timing

In an application recording sensor data I record video with OpenCV2 to have a video as a reference to the sensor data. Now dropping frames here and there is not a problem, but the loss seems to get worse the longer the measurement is. After filming a stop watch for 45 minutes the video was only about 33 minutes long(but obviously showed the 45 minutes from the watch on the screen).

What are good ways to use the recorded footage in a syncronized way? I could for example for every frame I add to the video a timestamp into a vector or I could do a timestamp each minute and spread the video out if need be. Are there any known methods to do this or do I have implement this myself? Is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: first problem ist that you have to choose a fixed fps for recording, which is not equal to the real fps.

Comment: can you please elaborate why that is and how to correctly choose a framerate for recording?

Comment: I think it is not possible in advance. You could remember the timestamps of each frame and create a better video in a post processing step, or you could try. to find another video library and containet format that supports timestamps directly. Another approach could be to first analyze your capturing for a few seconds minutes and observe the actual fps, but this will only work if fos and number of frame drops are quite constant over time.

Comment: well my idea would be to set the fps to what the camera says it can do and compensate for frame drops by duplicating a frame every x frames, and calculate X based on the amount of frames I got in a certain period. I was just wondering if there was a better way in opencv or if anyone has already dealt with this problem effectively

Comment: would be one possible approach, but keep in mind that the camera spec might not give prefect fps information or the camera timing might not be perfect. Maybe it will be better to observe the real occuring fps (counting images and looking at wall time) on the fly and add duplicate images if needed.